# Get all user for role or all roles for user

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am using `Identity 2` and `EF 6` and I would like to get a list of role objects for a user id or a list of user object for a roleId.

```
IEnumerable<TRole> GetUserRoles<TRole>(string userId) where TRole : class, IRole<string>

IEnumerable<TUser> GetRoleUsers<TUser>(string roleId) where TUser : class, IUser<string>
```

Entity framework does not appear to expose the linking table for the relationship between `TUser` and `TRole` so even using EF seems tricky.

It looks like the only way to do it close to efficiently is to query the database directly using SQL.

Does anyone have a solution to implementing these methods within the frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Entity Framework solution you can use SQL-like query expressions

```
public IEnumerable<TRole> GetUserRoles<TRole>(string userId) where TRole : class, IRole<string>
{
    return (from ur in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
            where ur.UserId == userId
            join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
            select r) as IEnumerable<TRole>;
}

public IEnumerable<TUser> GetRoleUsers<TUser>(string roleId) where TUser : class, IUser<string>
{
    return (from ur in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
            where ur.RoleId == roleId
            join u in db.Users on ur.UserId equals u.Id
            select u) as IEnumerable<TUser>;
}
```